# How to evaluate a list of cards in bslib::layout_column_wrap?

Tags: r, shiny, htmltools, bslib

I am trying to display a list of cards in a 2d grid using the function `bslib::layout_column_wrap()`. However, I get a 1d grid with the cards positioned in one column instead of multiple columns. See a minimal reproducible example below:

```
library(tidyverse); library(htmlwidgets); library(bslib)

cards_list <- list(
  card(card_body("card 1")),
  card(card_body("card 2"))      
)

layout_column_wrap(width=0.5, cards_list, heights_equal="all", fixed_width=T, fill=T)
```

When listing the elements of the list, it works fine (see below). However, this is not feasible because my list has hundreds of cards. Can anyone assist me with that?

```
layout_column_wrap(width=0.5, cards_list[1], cards_list[2], heights_equal="all", fixed_width=T, fill=T)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One option to pass your list of cards to `layout_column_wrap` would be to use splice operator `!!!` from `rlang`:

```
library(tidyverse)
library(htmlwidgets)
library(bslib)

layout_column_wrap(
  width = 0.5,
  !!!cards_list,
  heights_equal = "all", fixed_width = TRUE, fill = TRUE
)
```

Or using `do.call`:

```
do.call(
  layout_column_wrap,
  c(
    list(width = 0.5, heights_equal = "all", fixed_width = TRUE, fill = TRUE),
    cards_list
  )
)
```

[image]